# Find all solutions to the equation:$3^{\sin x} \cos x-3^{\cos x} \sin x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all solutions to the equation:
$3^{\sin x} \cos x-3^{\cos x} \sin x=0$

My attempt:
$3^{\sin x} \cos x-3^{\cos x} \sin x=0\implies 3^{\sin x} \cos x=3^{\cos x} \sin x\implies3^{\sin x-\cos x}=\tan x.$

I have found that $x=45^{\circ}$ or $225^{\circ}$ are satisfying the equation.

But,I don't know if these are the only solutions.
If these are the only solutions,then how to prove it?

Any guidance is welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: $ \ 3^{\sin x - \cos x} \ $ is always positive and has period $ \ 2\pi \ \ , $ while $ \ \tan x \ $ has period $ \ \pi \ $ and is positive on $ \ (0 \ , \ \frac{\pi}{2}) \ $ and $ \   \ (\pi \ , \ \frac{3\pi}{2} ) \ \ . $ Both function are continuous on their domains, so the Intermediate Value Theorem can be applied.  Choose values that will show there is an intersection of function curves in the first and third quadrants (although you have already found those intersections).  Compare the derivatives at those points.

Comment: @boojum, would you post your solution?

Comment: [This plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+3%5E%28sin%28x%29%29*cos%28x%29-3%5E%28cos%28x%29%29*sin%28x%29+from+0+to+2*pi&dataset=) shows there ae two roots per period. You already know their values, which can be verified by substitution. "Look at a plot" is usually not accepted as a proof, but you can verify certain facts about its shape with calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x \in [0,2\pi]$. Rewrite it : $3^{\cos x}\sin x = 3^{\sin x}\cos x$. If $\sin x > 0 \implies \cos x > 0$ and the same for the case negative sign. Thus you might consider $x \in (0,\pi/2)\cup(\pi, 3\pi/2)$. For the first case, rewrite further: $\dfrac{3^{\sin x}}{\sin x}= \dfrac{3^{\cos x}}{\cos x}$. Consider $f(t) = \dfrac{3^t}{t}$. We have: $f'(t) = \dfrac{t3^t\ln 3 - 3^t}{t^2}= \dfrac{3^t(t\ln 3 - 1)}{t^2}= 0 \implies t = \dfrac{1}{\ln 3}$. Observe that $\dfrac{1}{\ln 3} = 0.91024 > 0.78539 =\dfrac{\pi}{4} > 0$. So if $0 < t < \pi/4 \implies f'(t) < 0$, and in this interval $0 <\sin x < \cos x\implies f(\sin x) > f(\cos x)\implies \dfrac{3^{\sin x}}{\sin x} > \dfrac{3^{\cos x}}{\cos x}$. Thus the equation has no solution. If $\pi/4 < t < \dfrac{1}{\ln 3}\implies f'(t) < 0$ and on this interval $0 < \cos x < \sin x\implies f(\cos x) > f(\sin x) \implies \dfrac{3^{\cos x}}{\cos x} > \dfrac{3^{\sin x}}{\sin x}$. Thus the equation also has no solution on this interval. At $x=\pi/4$, the equation holds and therefore $x = \pi/4$ is a solution. If $\dfrac{1}{\ln 3} < t \le \pi/2\implies f'(t) > 0$ and on this interval $\sin x > \cos x \implies f(\sin x) > f(\cos x)\implies \dfrac{3^{\sin x}}{\sin x} > \dfrac{3^{\cos x}}{\cos x}$. So the equation has no solution on this interval. At $t = \dfrac{1}{\ln 3} = 0.91024$, $\dfrac{3^{\sin(0.91024)}}{\sin(0.91024)}= 3.01525 < 3.19806 = \dfrac{3^{\cos(0.91024)}}{\cos(0.91024)}$. Thus $x = \dfrac{1}{\ln 3}$ is not a solution.Thus there is only one solution on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ and that solution is $x = \pi/4 = 45^{\circ}$. Similarly you can show that the other solution is $x = 5\pi/4 = 225^{\circ}$, and this completes the proof that there are only two named solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You are pretty much at the solution.
You have 3^{Sin x - Cos x} = Sin x/Cos x.
As you noticed at x = pi/4 or 5pi/4, both sides become equal. In fact this would hold for all x where sin x = cos x as 3^(0) = 1 = RHS.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).